# Get value of input from step to step checkout page

Tags: magento2.3, checkout

I added a custom input to shipping step and i want to retrieve its value in order succes step

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save custom input value on database when user continue from shipping step and then you can retrieve custom input value in order success page.